# Fizz Buzz return value javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, fizzbuzz

I'm having an assignment where I have to do the FizzBuzz game in Javascript.
The problem is my loop stops after the first iteration and only return the first value (4). I may be blind to my code but I can't find where the error(s) is. 
If you could please push me in the right direction I'd be happy. Thanks in advance. Regards, Thomas.

```
function fizzBuzz(start, stop) {

    for(var i = start; i <= stop; i++) {
        if (i % 3 == 0) {
            return "fizz";
        }else if( i % 5 == 0) {
            return "buzz";
        }else if(i % 15 == 0) {
            return "fizz buzz";
        }else {
            return i;
        }
    }
}

ANSWER = (fizzBuzz(4, 22));
```

New code:

```
function fizzBuzz(start, stop) {

for(var i = start; i <= stop; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) {
        document.write ("Fizz Buzz");
    }else if(i % 3 == 0) {
        document.write ("Fizz");
    }else if(i % 5 == 0) {
        document.write ("Buzz");
    }else {
        document.write(i);
    }
}
}

ANSWER = (fizzBuzz(4, 22));
```

It returns: Answer = undefined

Comment: Lol and this is why you should try to fix your problem yourself by debugging, you would have saved yourself from asking an embarrassing question.

Comment: Nobody should be embarrassed to ask a question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Im guessing your suppose to print Fizz Buzz if the number is divisible by both 5 and 3?  You may want to change the else if(i %15 == 0) line. To be more the first condition and be more like if((i % 3 == 0) && (i % 5 == 0)) ...  Think about it.  15 % 3 == 0 thus not getting to that last else if....

Comment: i think you miss the whole point of fizzbuzz if you have to ask around...

Answer (score 4):

When your code encounters the `return` statement, the value given is returned from the whole function. This stops the `for` loop from iterating any further.

These are the questions you'll need to ask yourself:

- What do you want to the `fizzBuzz` function to do? Should it print the text somewhere, or should it return a value?
- If `fizzBuzz` should return a value, what would you expect that it returns? One line of text? Multiple lines of text all at once?

Comment: So I should use 'document.write' instead then?

Comment: Yes, that would be one way to do it.

Comment: Right. OP, another thing to ask yourself is if a number is divisible by 15, what does that say about other numbers by which it may be divisible?

Comment: I'd like to have the string printed out in the 'Answer=' but as long as I can get the loop to work I hope I can figure the rest out for my self.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever branch is taken within your for loop, there is always a `return` which exits the funtion with a return value. So, when you start with 4, the program enters the else branch and returns 4.

What you want is to print the value instead of returning from the function.

Also, I can see a logical error in the code. Assume i is 15, which is divisible by 3 and 5. Your program will go into the `i % 3` branch and return "fizz" instead of "fizz buzz". You may want to change your if statements and/or work with string concatenation.

Hope I could help. ;)

Answer (score 0):

One of the best solution in javascript to the fizzbuzz problem

```
const fizzbuzz = (start, stop) => {
  const arr = [];
  let str;
  for(let i=start; i<=stop; i++) {
    str = "";
    if(i%3===0) {
      str = "fizz";
    }
    if(i%5===0) {
      str += "buzz";
    }
    arr.push(str||i);
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(fizzbuzz(0, 105));
```